# UIWebView only calls didFailLoadWithError once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a native iPhone app that just loads a website using `UIWebView`. I implemented the `UIWebViewDelegate` function `didFailLoadWithError` to display an error message when the user attempts to use the app without an Internet connection. The alert box shows up the first time I build and run the app, but does not appear thereafter. If I click the home button, then tap my app again, I just see a blank UIWebView. It's as if it's not trying to load the page again, so it never triggers `didFailLoadWithError`. This is just a simple app without saving and reloading of state, so shouldn't reloading the app re-run all my code, including the attempted loading of the website?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.site.com"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark UIWebView delegate


- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
    //[myActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [error code]]);

    if ([error code] != USER_STOPPED_LOAD) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Connection Error!" 
                                    message:@"You must be connected to the Internet to use Site." 
                                   delegate:nil 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because it only gets sent to the background when you click the Home button! To restart the app, kill it using the multitasking bar.

Comment: I see. So if I open 50 applications and suspend all of them, my RAM would be clogged up? I don't think Apple should have done this because non-techy users of the iPhone don't know about RAM.

Comment: The system will automatically select apps to be terminated in case of memory running low. Don't worry about the multitasking system, a few tens of million people have been field-testing it for almost a year now ;-)